# If we have n many simultaneous linearly independent and not necesseraly linear simultaneous equations does it mean we have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to investigate the degrees of freedoms of simultaneous equations of the form
$$
\begin{cases}
F_1 (x_1,..,x_n)=0 \\
\quad \quad \quad\vdots \\
F_n (x_1,..,x_n)=0
\end{cases}
$$
where $F_i$ are linearly independent functions from one another but **not necessarily linear functions**.

**Question:** Does this equation specify $x_1,..x_n$ uniquely? Moreover, how do we deal with degrees of freedom here? Is the result analogous to when $F_i$ are linear functions?

**Discussion:** Clearly this is true for linear $F_i$ but I am having issues with proving/disproving the claim for non linear ones. For polynomials, I was thinking that one use some sort of Fourier expansion and argue for the basis, however, this is not nearly general enough.

Comment: Suppose you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and your equations are $x$ and $x^2$. These two are linearly independent but the solution set is one dimensional.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense now. Could you post this as an answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: If you are interested in these type of questions, then you might  find complete intersections compelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and your equations are $x$ and $x^2$. These two are linearly independent but the solution set is one dimensional.